# How to change anchor color when targeted #div is selected or scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to change the color of a specific anchor when that anchors target is in view. I have a jquery script that almost works, in that it changes the anchor color but not until I scroll down 10px or so from the target. Also the height of the targeted divs and their distance from the top of the page varies. I have tried using padding and margins, and have found some success with targeting different elements within the divs such as #div h1, but I would rather just target the #div.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('#main-page').position().top){
        $("#main").css("color","#ff2a2a");
        $("#news,#about").css("color","#fff");
    }
});
```

...and then I repeat that for however many sections are on the page.

Comment: If it changes colour when it's not in view, how would you know?

Comment: I meant 10px from the top of the target as I scroll down it.

Comment: do you have some kind of css for the tags you are using?  It could be you probably are using something like a padding or margin for the parent div